# PyTorch "NCCL error: unhandled system error" during backprop

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed-computing

I am trying to do distributed training with PyTorch and encountered a problem. 
This runtime error occurs during backprop (first batch, first epoch).

```
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpi4py/__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpi4py/run.py", line 196, in main
    run_command_line(args)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpi4py/run.py", line 47, in run_command_line
    run_path(sys.argv[0], run_name='__main__')
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "project/main.py", line 115, in <module>
    trainer.run(config["epochs"])
  File "/home/user/project/trainer/trainer.py", line 107, in run
    self.run_epoch()
  File "/home/user/project/trainer/trainer.py", line 70, in run_epoch
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 107, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 93, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: NCCL error in: /pytorch/torch/lib/c10d/ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:272, unhandled system error
```

I use MPI for automatic rank assignment and NCCL as main back-end.
Initialization is done through file on a shared file system.
Each process uses 2 GPUs, processes run on different nodes.
Environment variable `NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME` is set.
Previously, this code was working fine :(

Does anyone know why this error may occur?

**UPD 13/05/19:** There has been has progress. 
Initially error occurred on model initialization, now on first backward pass.

Answer (score 0):

`unhandled system error` means there are some underlying errors on the NCCL side. You should first rerun your code with `NCCL_DEBUG=INFO`. Then figure out what the error is from the debugging log (especially the warnings in log).

An example is given at [Pytorch "NCCL error": unhandled system error, NCCL version 2.4.8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075390/pytorch-nccl-error-unhandled-system-error-nccl-version-2-4-8)

Answer (score -2):

```
RuntimeError: NCCL error in: /pytorch/torch/lib/c10d/ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:272, unhandled system error
```

this error usually means there are some differences between codes on different nodes, it may be detected by nccl to trig this error, check your scripts, usually, it happens after you modify one script copy while forgetting modifying others.