# How to solve dist.init_process_group from hanging (or deadlocks)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

I was to set up DDP (distributed data parallel) on a DGX A100 but it doesn't work. Whenever I try to run it simply hangs. My code is super simple just spawning 4 processes for 4 gpus (for the sake of debugging I simply destroy the group immediately but it doesn't even reach there):

```
def find_free_port():
    """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365265/on-localhost-how-do-i-pick-a-free-port-number """
    import socket
    from contextlib import closing

    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        return str(s.getsockname()[1])

def setup_process(rank, world_size, backend='gloo'):
    """
    Initialize the distributed environment (for each process).

    gloo: is a collective communications library (https://github.com/facebookincubator/gloo). My understanding is that
    it's a library/API for process to communicate/coordinate with each other/master. It's a backend library.

    export NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME=eth0
    export NCCL_IB_DISABLE=1

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075390/about-pytorch-nccl-error-unhandled-system-error-nccl-version-2-4-8

    https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#common-environment-variables
    """
    if rank != -1:  # -1 rank indicates serial code
        print(f'setting up rank={rank} (with world_size={world_size})')
        # MASTER_ADDR = 'localhost'
        MASTER_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
        MASTER_PORT = find_free_port()
        # set up the master's ip address so this child process can coordinate
        os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = MASTER_ADDR
        print(f"{MASTER_ADDR=}")
        os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = MASTER_PORT
        print(f"{MASTER_PORT}")

        # - use NCCL if you are using gpus: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html#communication-backends
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            # unsure if this is really needed
            # os.environ['NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME'] = 'eth0'
            # os.environ['NCCL_IB_DISABLE'] = '1'
            backend = 'nccl'
        print(f'{backend=}')
        # Initializes the default distributed process group, and this will also initialize the distributed package.
        dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
        # dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
        # dist.init_process_group(backend='nccl', init_method='env://', world_size=world_size, rank=rank)
        print(f'--> done setting up rank={rank}')
        dist.destroy_process_group()

mp.spawn(setup_process, args=(4,), world_size=4)
```

why is this hanging?

nvidia-smi output:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri Mar  5 12:47:17 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.102.04   Driver Version: 450.102.04   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   26C    P0    51W / 400W |      0MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:0F:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   25C    P0    52W / 400W |      3MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:47:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   25C    P0    51W / 400W |      3MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:4E:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   25C    P0    51W / 400W |      3MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:87:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P0    52W / 400W |      3MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:90:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0    53W / 400W |      0MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:B7:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0    52W / 400W |      0MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:BD:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0   231W / 400W |   7500MiB / 40537MiB |     99%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    7   N/A  N/A    147243      C   python                           7497MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I set up ddp in this new machine?

---

## Update

btw I've successfully installed APEX because some other links say to do that but it still fails. For I did:

went to: https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex follwed their instructions

```
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```

but before the above [I had to update gcc](https://gist.github.com/goldsborough/d466f43e8ffc948ff92de7486c5216d6):

```
conda install -c psi4 gcc-5
```

it did install it as I successfully imported it but it didn't help.

---

Now it actually prints an error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 19, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
KeyboardInterrupt
Process SpawnProcess-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 19, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/miranda9/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 252, in train
    setup_process(rank, world_size=opts.world_size)
  File "/home/miranda9/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/distributed.py", line 85, in setup_process
    dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 436, in init_process_group
    store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 179, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = TCPStore(master_addr, master_port, world_size, start_daemon, timeout)
RuntimeError: connect() timed out.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

---

related:

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9696
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dist-init-process-group-hangs-silently/55347/2
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/imagenet-hang-on-dgx-1-when-using-multiple-gpus/61919
- apex suggestion: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/hangs-on-dist-init-process-group-in-distribute-py/44686
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15638
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/53395

Comment: It looks like with your update you're getting connection issues rather than process spawning issues. Can you print out the variables being passed to form the connections?

Comment: My answer should solve the error you posted, i.e. init_process_group hanging while attempting to connect via TCPStore.  Is there another issue you're still having after fixing that one?

Comment: @MarkH apologies mark, I ran out of time. I've not had the cycles to test it myself but I read your answer and I believe that works - each process needs to have the same master port while I am getting a different one for each by accident. Will accept and upvote (and delete these unnecessary comments) as soon as I get the cycles to test it (plan is to do it today actually).

Answer (score 6):

The following fixes are based on [Writing Distributed Applications with PyTorch, Initialization Methods](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html#initialization-methods).

**Issue 1:**

It will hang unless you pass in `nprocs=world_size` to `mp.spawn()`.  In other words, it's waiting for the "whole world" to show up, process-wise.

---

**Issue 2:**

The MASTER_ADDR and MASTER_PORT need to be the same in each process' environment and need to be a free address:port combination on the machine where the process with rank 0 will be run.

---

Both of these are implied or directly read from the following quote from the link above (emphasis added):

> **Environment Variable**
>
> We have been using the environment variable initialization method
> throughout this tutorial. By setting the following four environment
> variables on all machines, all processes will be able to properly
> connect to the master, obtain information about the other processes,
> and finally handshake with them.
>
> MASTER_PORT: **A free port on the machine that will host the process *with rank 0***.
>
> MASTER_ADDR: **IP address of the machine that will host the process *with rank 0***.
>
> WORLD_SIZE: The total **number of processes**, so that the master knows **how many workers to wait for**.
>
> RANK: Rank of each process, so they will know whether it is the master of a worker.

---

Here's some code to demonstrate both of those in action:

```python
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch.distributed as dist
import os

def find_free_port():
    """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365265/on-localhost-how-do-i-pick-a-free-port-number """
    import socket
    from contextlib import closing

    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        return str(s.getsockname()[1])


def setup_process(rank, master_addr, master_port, world_size, backend='gloo'):
    print(f'setting up {rank=} {world_size=} {backend=}')

    # set up the master's ip address so this child process can coordinate
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = master_addr
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = master_port
    print(f"{master_addr=} {master_port=}")

    # Initializes the default distributed process group, and this will also initialize the distributed package.
    dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
    print(f"{rank=} init complete")
    dist.destroy_process_group()
    print(f"{rank=} destroy complete")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    world_size = 4
    master_addr = '127.0.0.1'
    master_port = find_free_port()
    mp.spawn(setup_process, args=(master_addr,master_port,world_size,), nprocs=world_size)
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion but somehow the code still freezes and the init_process_group execution isn't completed. I have uploaded a demo code here which follows your code snippet. [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/rushi-the-neural-arch/e83eb170cac47eca859282b423bca262) Can you please let me know what could be the potential issue here?? Thanks!

Comment: Why is your master addr/master port changing every time??