# Install Pytorch dependencies (torchtext + torchdata + torch) with cuda and A100 GPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu

For my project, I need to use pytorch, torchtext, and torchdata.
However, I get the following error with the following versions

torch==1.12.0+cu102

torchtext==0.13.0

torchdata==0.4.0

```
NVIDIA A100-PCIE-40GB with CUDA capability sm_80 is not compatible with the current PyTorch installation
```

My system is a remote machine with Fedora Linux that I can only access via SSH. I do not have root access or full priviliges, so no sudo shananigans please. Unfortunately, I cannot try the following option: [How does one use Pytorch (+ cuda) with an A100 GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992585/how-does-one-use-pytorch-cuda-with-an-a100-gpu) because I cannot find the corresponding torchdata and torchtext versions (they only seem to start at torch 1.11.0). How do I solve this issue? Many thanks for your help.

I also have some issues installing pytorch with a specific cuda version. For example:

```
pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.11.0+cu113 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.11.0+cu113
```

An alternative solution would be to get rid off torchtext altogether. Currently, I need it to load pretrained embedding vectors:

```
glove = torchtext.vocab.GloVe(name='twitter.27B', dim=100)
```

Loading the file "glove.twitter.27B.100d.txt" would obviate my need for torchtext, so I will accept that as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by installing a newer cuda version (> 1.10)

```
pip install torch==1.12.0+cu116 torchvision==0.13.0+cu116 torchaudio==0.12.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116 --no-cache-dir
```

`--no-cache-dir` was needed because the process was killed every time I tried without.